# Disable touchMove but enable touch

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, dom-events

I have a problem with JavaScript events, I need to disable `touchMove` for disabling swipes on a page but there I have button and touch event should be enabled. I tried next code:

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

But its disabling not just `touchmove` but ordinary touch also. How to enable `touch` event?

Comment: In your event listener check whether the button (e.g. by comparing id's or css classes) has been touched and do nothing it this case. Otherwise call the *preventDefault* method. The [*event.target*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property will be useful for that.